# How to redirect to a different ejs file in the same folder in node.js

Tags: node.js, ejs

Whenever I'm trying to redirect my `node.js` file (`form.js`) to the same page using `res.redirect("/");` it is working!

But when I'm trying to redirect to a different file(`welcome.ejs`) in the same folder using `res.redirect("/welcome");` it is not working.

My `welcome.ejs` file has this sentence in it `<h1>Welcome Home</h1>` and that's it.

My mysql database is working just fine and I can see the message "rows affected". So I'm pretty sure there is no issue there. 
I'm not even getting any errors.

I cannot understand why I cannot redirect to `welcome.ejs` page but I can redirect to home page(`home.ejs` or `"/"`). In the browser the message says "cannot get /welcome"

I even tried return `res.redirect(/welcome)` or `res.redirect("/welcome.ejs")` but it didn't work!

my folder structure is `views/home.ejs` & `views/welcome.ejs`.

**Can anyone please help me with this?**

this is my `form.js` code

```
  app.get('/accountform', function(req, res) {
  var q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `Projects`";
  connection.query(q, function(err, results){

    if (err) throw err;
    var count = results[0].count;
    //res.send("We have " + count + " no of users.");
    res.render("accountform", {count: count});
   });

 app.post('/addproject', function(req, res){
  var project = {
   Project_No: req.body.Project_No,
   Project_Name: req.body.Project_Name,
   Status: req.body.Status,
   Project_Type: req.body.Project_Type

  };
  connection.query('insert into `Projects` SET ?', project, function(err, 
  result){
  console.log(err);
  console.log(result);

  res.redirect("/welcome");
   });
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I try something near to your code

this is my app.js

```
    const {getHomePage} = require('./routes/index');
    const {addPlayer} = require('./routes/player');


    app.get('/', getHomePage);
    app.post('/add', addPlayer);
```

routes/index.js

```
        module.exports = {
        getHomePage: (req, res) => {
            let query = "SELECT * FROM `players` ORDER BY id ASC"; 
            db.query(query, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.redirect('/');
                }
                res.render('index.ejs', {
                    title: "Welcome to Socka | View Players"
                    ,players: result
                });
            });
        },
        };
```

routes/player.js

```
         module.exports = {
            addPlayerPage: (req, res) => {
            res.render('add-player.ejs', {
                title: "Welcome to Socka | Add a new player"
                ,message: ''
            });
        },
        addPlayer: (req, res) => {
            if (!req.files) {
                return res.status(400).send("No files were uploaded.");
            }

            let message = '';
            let first_name = req.body.first_name;
            let last_name = req.body.last_name;
            let position = req.body.position;
            let number = req.body.number;
            let username = req.body.username;
            let uploadedFile = req.files.image;
            let image_name = uploadedFile.name;
            let fileExtension = uploadedFile.mimetype.split('/')[1];
            image_name = username + '.' + fileExtension;

            let usernameQuery = "SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE user_name = '" + username + 
                  "'";

            db.query(usernameQuery, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    message = 'Username already exists';
                    res.render('add-player.ejs', {
                        message,
                        title: "Welcome to Socka | Add a new player"
                    });
                } else {
                    if (uploadedFile.mimetype === 'image/png' || uploadedFile.mimetype === 
                     'image/jpeg' || uploadedFile.mimetype === 'image/gif') {

                        uploadedFile.mv(`public/assets/img/${image_name}`, (err ) => {
                            if (err) {
                                return res.status(500).send(err);
                            }

                            let query = "INSERT INTO `players` (first_name, last_name, 
                     position, number, image, user_name) VALUES ('" +
                                first_name + "', '" + last_name + "', '" + position + "', '" 
                     + number + "', '" + image_name + "', '" + username + "')";
                            db.query(query, (err, result) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                                }
                                res.redirect('/');
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        message = "Invalid File format. Only 'gif', 'jpeg' and 'png' images 
                    are allowed.";
                        res.render('add-player.ejs', {
                            message,
                            title: "Welcome to Socka | Add a new player"
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
          }
         }
```

i have index.ejs and addplayer.ejs in views folder

this is my full github code
https://github.com/gayathribrittany/nodeapp